# How to force the use of AMD R7 265 in Notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that uses two video cards controlled only by software?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics, mesa

I would like to run my **R7-265** video card in my ubuntu **18.04** LTS.
The problem is that you do not provide support since ubuntu 14.04 LTS later. (the screen below)

[image]

And I'd like to use my video card.
How do I run it without official driver?
Is the **MESA** driver I need to configure?
How do I install this driver?
SO I DID IT
I installed mesa-util

[image]

But it still showing intel graphic card...

[image]

I've been researching ways to configure but I have not found a safe step on the internet.

Is there a way to FORCE the use via software?
It was so easy with the catalyst ...

Comment: There is no special driver you need to do. The stock drivers included in Ubuntu should work. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: How i will use my AMD if my steam apear showing intel graphic card?

Comment: dobey, thank you, but this post you posted it is not what i need.
I'm not in the moment to install the driver to mesa, i m in the moment to force the use in 2 graphics cards controlled by sofrware...

Comment: You've basically deleted the entire question and asked a new question, through liberal use of the edit feature, since I suggested that as a duplicate.